# No monochromatic arithmetic progression

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic-progressions

Given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, what is the minimum value of $m$ for which we can color $1,2,\dots,n$ in $m$ colors such that no three numbers of the same color form an arithmetic progression?

Let $f(n)$ denote the specified value. For small values of $n$, we have $f(1)=f(2)=1$, $f(n)=2$ for $3\leq n\leq 8$, and I believe $f(9)=3$. Might the answer be $\lfloor\log_3n\rfloor+1$?

Comment: Given the required coloring of the discrete segment $n=\{1,\dots, n\}$, each monochromatic set $A$ should be a so-called *Sidon’s set* or $B_2$-sequence. Such sets were investigated by many authors (for survey and references see section 4.1 of C. Pomerance, A. Sárközy. Combinatorial number theory. In Handbook of Combinatorics, chapter 20, pages 967-1018. Elsevier Publ., 1995). In particular, Erdős and Turán showed, that $|A|\le\sqrt{n}(1+o(1))$, which implies that $m\ge \sqrt{n}(1+o(1))$.

Comment: From the other hand, the minimum value of $m$ which you are asking,  equals the minimum value of $m$ such that [van der Waerden number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden_number)  $W(m, 3)>n$.